# Automated Playlist Creation Using Timestamps & Durations

Tags: debian, wav, playlist

With Debian Linux as my preferred platform, I would like to automate the creation of playlists using a list of timestamps and durations.

I will use the list of timestamps to either dice up a wave file into smaller chunks or to generate a playlist that will jump to the correct spot in the wav file without user intervention.

Does anyone know of a program that can do this type of thing?  I've looked at lamemp3 but it doesn't seem to be able to use external data, such as a list of timestamps, to produce clips from a larger file.

What about using Python to generate an playlist file that can be read by a regular audio player, like Windows Media?  What type of playlist format would be required for this?

Thanks in advance.